# How to decorate WP_Widget_Text?

Tags: widgets

Im trying to do an extended WP_Widget_Text, and to be professional, lets use a decorated design pattern.
This is all I have:

```
<?php
namespace X;

class CustomHtml extends \WP_Widget
{
    /**
     * @var \WP_Widget_Text
     */
    private $decoratedWidget;

    /**
     * constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'blah',
            'blah2',
            ['description' => 'gahhff']
        );
        $this->decoratedWidget = new \WP_Widget_Text();
    }


    /**
     * Widget beállításokat tartalmazó űrlap.
     * @param $instance
     */
    public function form($instance)
    {
        echo '<hr>';
        $this->decoratedWidget->form($instance);
        echo '<hr>';
    }

    /**
     * @param $new_instance
     * @param $old_instance
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $this->decoratedWidget->update($new_instance, $old_instance);
        return $new_instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     */
    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $this->decoratedWidget->widget($args, $instance);
    }
}
```

and as it was expected, it wont work. On "form" nothing showns. It does, but "hidden". How to extend it properly?

Comment: I can see you ignore the return value of the `update` method, but I don't believe that the decorate pattern works well here. You've also missed out the constructor arguments. If your goal is to add lines above and underneath that widget,  you'd be better off with a CSS rule such as `.wp-widget { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }`. Modifying widgets like this is highly unusual, and I would not recommend this particular route, applying an OO pattern from a book doesn't make the code professional, instead focus on readable, clean, testable code.

Comment: then what else can I do?